# How to get rid of empty vertical space in a table?

Tags: tables, spacing, lists, vertical

I'm trying to remove the empty white space in my table after the list.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=22.5mm,right=22.5mm,top=30mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Key economic benefits of the project.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}L>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}}
    \toprule
    Traffic Benefits & Wider Economic Benefits & Contribution to GDP \\ 
    \midrule
    \$1,580 million & \$800 million to \$1,300 million & \$600 million to \$1,100 million \\
    \midrule
    \vspace{-5mm}\begin{itemize}
        \setlength\itemsep{0em}
        \item Travel time savings
        \item Congestion cost savings
        \item Reduced fuel consumption
        \item Vehicle operating cost savings
        \item Other
    \end{itemize} & 
    \vspace{-5mm}\begin{itemize}
        \setlength\itemsep{0em}
        \item Local job generation (estimated to be around 18,500 jobs)
        \item Improved productivity from reduced travel time
        \item Increased accessibility providing opportunities for greater economic growth
    \end{itemize} &
    \vspace{-5mm}\begin{itemize}
        \item Increased revenue from taxes – from increased employment productivity and growth
    \end{itemize} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just replace the last \\ by \\\[-1em].

Comment: Thanks, that was easy!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With use of the `itemize`'s options `after`, `before` and `nosep` provided by `enumitem` package. I also would have equal width of all columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hmargin=22.5mm,vmargin=30mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setlist[itemize]{leftmargin=*}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,                                % <---
                  leftmargin=*,
                  before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip},    % <---
                  after =\vspace{-1.8\baselineskip}}    % <---
\caption{Key economic benefits of the project.}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LLL @{}}               % <---
    \toprule
Traffic Benefits & Wider Economic Benefits & Contribution to GDP \\
    \midrule
\$1,580 million  & \$800 million to \$1,300 million & \$600 million to \$1,100 million \\
    \midrule
\begin{itemize}
    \item Travel time savings
    \item Congestion cost savings
    \item Reduced fuel consumption
    \item Vehicle operating cost savings
    \item Other
\end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
                    \item Local job generation (estimated to be around 18,500 jobs)
                    \item Improved productivity from reduced travel time
                    \item Increased accessibility providing opportunities for greater economic growth
                \end{itemize} & \begin{itemize}
                                  \item Increased revenue from taxes – from increased employment productivity and growth
                                \end{itemize} \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```